# MySQL Create a distribution or frequency list of similar items across user shopping carts

Tags: mysql, grouping, cluster-analysis, data-mining, behavior

It has been a while since I have posted this question; just curious if anyone can take an honest stab at it.

Here is the table I have

```
+----------------------+
| cart_product_table   |
+----------------------+
| cartID  | productID  |
+---------+------------+
| 1       | 123        |
| 1       | 451        |
| 1       | 998        |
| 1       | 12         |
| 2       | 998        |
| 2       | 12         |
| 2       | 123        |
| 2       | 1          |
| 3       | 123        | 
| 3       | 564        |
+---------+------------+
```

I am looking for a way to `cluster` or `group` carts together that have similar items. For instance, product 123 is in carts 1 and 3, products 123 and 12 are in carts 1 and 2.

What is the best way to go about this type of problem? The clusters/groups are not predefined, for it depends on the data.

Essentially, we are trying to gage customer behavior patterns by observing similar items in their carts.

Any non-coding helpful advice as far as the approach goes is also welcomed. Can a simple cluster analysis be done in excel? Just curious.

Comment: How about counting the items...get the top five and make a graph

Comment: how many numbers are going to be used as a cluster? you show one common, and two common... any deeper than that?

Comment: That number is not defined a-priori and the grouping/how many groups should be defined by the data that exists. It's not possible to decide beforehand how many clusters there will be.

Answer (score 0):

Friends don't let friends use MySQL or Excel for data analysis.

You are not looking for cluster analysis.

What you are looking for is **frequent itemset mining**.

See also: [Is it possible to run apriori association rule in mysql statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203227/is-it-possible-to-run-apriori-association-rule-in-mysql-statement)

Comment: can you unpack that statement and give some examples? I googled it up but some guided comments will help

Comment: Too broad to unpack. Ask more precisely. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm